# How to use antd icons in CSS pseudo-elements

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm currently getting an icon like this:

```
import { Icon } from "antd";
...

// inside react component:
<div className="someclass">
  <Icon type="thunderbolt" /> 
</div>
```

What I really want to do is this, with CSS:

```
div.someclass::before {
  content: "\E6EA"; // pretend this is the correct thunderbolt icon code
}
```

Now I *think* I'm reading that `antd` doesn't use a font for icons, but direct SVG.  Is that correct?  Does that mean that inserting icons with CSS is not possible with `antd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use CSS pseudo-elements now, they replaced for SVG (since version `3.9.0`). You can [read](https://ant.design/components/icon/#About-SVG-icons) it here and the pr discussion why [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/10353).

Comment: Can you also explicitly answer the question?  e.g. "No, you can't use CSS pseudo-elements now", if that is indeed the answer.